# Array of shorted URLs using foreach loop through and how to resolve each url with nodejs TALL

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

In my problem issue is very simple but I do not get it, HOW to do it!

I have 2 shortened URL in a array;
[ 'URL1',
  'URL2'
]
and I am trying to use foreach with TALL to open each shortened url and check the REAL url.

I cant get it done, at least
https://www.npmjs.com/package/tall

```
if (data) {

    let urls = getUrls(www);
    let array = Array.from(urls);


    var urlit = array.map((aurl) => aurl);


    for(var i = 0; i < urlit.length; i++){
        var urlData = urlit[i];
        let newUrls = tall(urlit[i]);

        context.log(i+1, urlData);
        context.log(newUrls);
     };
```

All-in-all; I have an array of urls => how it open each url and if its correct one and add it into variable? (as Tall use promises)

Hope I am enough clear with the issue and thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+foreach+promise

Comment: When working with promises (and in general), don't use `forEach`.

Comment: Well, maybe this is what i am searching that what is the best approach for this. How to do it another way?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this (StackOverflow does not allow to post shortened URLs even in code fragments, so I've masked them by concatenating):

```js
'use strict';

const { tall } = require('tall');

const urls = [
  'https://' + 't.co/og6viaRxnr',
  'https://' + 't.co/pIq3NBQIwD',
];

(async function asyncFunc() {
  try {
    for (const url of urls) {
      const unshortenedUrl = await tall(url);
      console.log(unshortenedUrl);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Output:

```
https://github.blog/changelog/2019-02-21-organization-wide-community-health-files/
https://github.blog/changelog/2019-02-21-re-request-review-on-a-pull-request/
```

====================== for the fragment in the comment:

```js
'use strict';

const { tall } = require('tall');

(async function asyncFunc() {
  try {
    if (data) {
      let urls = getUrls(www);
      let array = Array.from(urls);
      var urlit = array.map((aurl) => aurl);


      for(var i = 0; i < urlit.length; i++){
        var urlData = urlit[i];
        let newUrls = await tall(urlit[i]);

        context.log(i+1, urlData);
        context.log(newUrls);
      };
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Comment: data = "the urls"

if (data) {

        let urls = getUrls(www);
        let array = Array.from(urls);


        var urlit = array.map((aurl) => aurl);


        for(var i = 0; i < urlit.length; i++){
            var urlData = urlit[i];
            let newUrls = tall(urlit[i]);

            context.log(i+1, urlData);
            context.log(newUrls);
         };

In this situation I have now inside newUrls 3x Promise pending which is definetly progress but I would like to understand and learn way use "i think promise.all" -> to solve this or am i totally lost?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I understand. I've added the example for this pattern (it just needs an `await` before `tall()` call) — though I do not know fully what the functions and data mean. Please, elaborate on your issue more.

Comment: Perhaps @JaySnewBie would like a single array of all the unshortened URL's after all the promises have completed (to do further processing). Or they would like to run tall on all the URL's at the same time, for performance reasons. Both would be solved by using promise.all.